# Different beheavior of get and mget in aggregation (R)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an character array (`chr [1:5]` named `keynn`) of column names on which I would like to perform an aggregation.
All elements of the array is a valid column name of the data frame (`mydata`), but it is a string and not the variable ("YEAR" instead of `mydata$YEAR`).

I tried using `get()` to return the column from the name and it works, for the first element, like so:

```
attach(mydata)
aggregate(mydata, by=list(get(keynn, .GlobalEnv)), FUN=length)
```

I tried using mget() since my array as more than one element, like this:

```
attach(mydata)
aggregate(mydata, by=list(mget(keynn, .GlobalEnv)), FUN=length)
```

but I get an error:

```
value for 'YEAR' not found.
```

How can I get the equivalent of get for multiple columns to aggregate by?

Thank you!

Comment: What is mget supposed to do vs get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not using `attach` in general

If you are just trying to get columns from `mydata` you can use `[` to index the list

```
aggregate(mydata, by = mydata[keynn], FUN = length)
```

should work -- and is very clear that you want to get `keynn` from `mydata`

The problem with using `attach` is that it adds `mydata` to the search path (not copying to the global environment)

try

```
 attach(mydata)
 mget(keynn, .GlobalEnv)
```

so if you were to use `mget` and `attach`, you need

```
 mget(keynn, .GlobalEnv, inherits = TRUE)
```

so that it will not just search in the global environment.

But that is more effort than  it is worth (IMHO)

The reason `get` works is that `inherits = TRUE` by default. You could thus use `lapply(keynn, get)` if `mydata` were attached, but again this ugly and unclear about what it is doing.

---

another approach would be to use `data.table`, which will evaluate the `by` argument within the data.table in question

```
 library(data.table)

 DT <- data.table(mydata)

 DT[, {what you want to aggregate} , by =keynn]
```

Note that keynn doesn't need to be a character vector of names, it can be  a list of names or a named list of functions of names etc

Comment: `aggregate(mydata, by = mydata[keynn], FUN = length)` worked great. Thank you. It is very appreciated.